# How to debug deployed Meteor app on the server side?

Tags: debugging, meteor

I have an app deployed on meteor.com, which after 2-5 days of working perfectly suddenly becomes unresponsive to requests. Restarting the app by deploying it again causes it to work properly.

What's the best way to debug this? I don't know how to reproduce the issue on my local server since it only happens intermittently.

Nothing seemed off in `meteor logs` other than this line:

`spiderable: phantomjs failed: { [Error: Command failed: ] killed: true, code: null, signal: 'SIGTERM' } stderr:`

I tried removing the spiderable smart package and the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor.com's hosting via `meteor deploy` will kill your app if its not visited for somewhere near 2-4 hours.

This doesn't mean that its dead though, if you load it up in your web browser it'll take a couple of seconds extra to get running again. It might take longer if you have a heavy startup load, though.

Meteor hasn't brought up details of its paid solutions yet, but if you want to keep your site up for longer it should automatically if it has a visit every hour or two. I'm not suggesting that its the best way to do it, but you could remotely ping it too.

Comment: The app doesn't respond even after over a minute of waiting. Additionally, the app serves a few hundred views per day so it's unlikely there is a 2-4 hour window with no traffic.